# Apple Notarization error "Team is not yet configured for notarization"

Tags: cocoa, xcode10, macos-mojave, macos-catalina, notarize

We notarized my Mac application from Apple multiple time with Developer ID certificate a week ago.

Now we notarized the same application with the same Developer ID certificate using Xcode 10. The result is an application notarization process failed for the following reason:

```
"status": "Rejected",  

"statusSummary": "Team is not yet configured for notarization",

"statusCode": 7000
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a known bug at Apple’s end. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118465.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a technical issue; it's an Apple Programs issue.

So you'll want to [contact Developer Programs](https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/SC1102/subtopic/30018/solution/EML/details). They should be able to resolve this.